# How do I make the button:hover state not triggered before moving cursor when the button is put under my cursor by code

Tags: html, css

Hard to explain, please take a look at the demo:

When you click *Button A*, the *Button A* will be removed and *Button B* appeared immediately in *Button A*'s location. However, since my cursor is exactly on the area inside *Button B*'s scope, the `:hover` style is immediately triggered.

I want to change this behavior to, after clicking *button A*, the user need to move the cursor to trigger the `:hover` state. If I do not move the mouse when I click the *button A*, the `:hover` for *Button B* will not be showed.

```js
$('button:eq(0)').click(function() {
  $('#b2').show();
  $(this).remove()
})
```

```css
#b2 {
  display: none
}

button:hover {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button A</button>
<button id="b2">Button B</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you cannot use the `:hover` pseudo from CSS in your case. The CSS hover pseudo-selector will always be active when you hover. The only way to stop it hovering is to change the element or the structure so that the hover pseudo-class does not take effect.

The way around that limitation is to not use the hover pseudo-class at all, and instead to use a `hover` class, in which you will use `onmouseover` to toggle the hover class for the menu item.

In this example, the second button doesn't immediately turn red. But as soon as you start moving your mouse it gets red as well.

You might be able to work around this using `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` instead. I just added this as a quick help, you should be able to work from there.

```js
$('button:eq(0)').click(function() {
  $('#b2').show();
  $(this).remove()
})

$("button").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("hover");
});
```

```css
#b2 {
  display: none
}

button.hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button A</button>
<button id="b2">Button B</button>
```